# Why is the Variable "api_key" not being recognized?

Tags: javascript, variables, openai-api

I try to pull the api key that is defined as the variable `api_key` in my file1.js file to my index2.html file where i make a javascript request to openai using the variable as authorization. I console logged the variable and it gets displayed in the browser log but when i make the request i keep getting the error `api_key is not defined`.

Heres my code:
file1.js:

```
export const api_key ='sk-...';
```

index2.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module">
      import { api_key } from './file1.js';
      console.log(api_key)
      const variableElement = document.getElementById('api_key');
      variableElement.textContent = api_key;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
    let cache = {};

    logo1.addEventListener("click", async function() {
      if (!option1Head.value 
        || option1Head.value === "Option 1" 
        || !idea1.value 
        || idea1.value === "idea 1") {
        alert("Please write something in the text fields");
        return;
      }
  
      const topic = idea.value + option1Head.value;
      if (cache[topic]) {
        window.alert(cache[topic]);
        return;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < bannedKeywords.length; i++) {
        if (topic.toLowerCase().includes(bannedKeywords[i])) {
          alert("The topic contains inappropriate content, please try another topic");
          return;
        }
      }
      
      const response = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-  003/completions", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${api_key}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          prompt: `Please generate a text about ${topic}.`,
          temperature: 0,
          max_tokens: 188,
          top_p: 0,
          frequency_penalty: 0,
          presence_penalty: 0,
        })
      });
      
      const data = await response.json();
      let words = "";
      data.choices[0].text.split(" ").forEach(word => {
        words += word + " ";
      });
      cache[topic] = words;
      window.alert(words);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Tangential, but this code is difficult to read.

Comment: I think `api_key` only exists inside the script element which has the type module. It likely won't be available to the non module script at the end of the document.